# How to add numbers into a table using SQL only on MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to add numbers from 100 to 9999 into a table using for loop. I have tried the following query:

```
DELIMITER //
BEGIN
   FOR phone_number IN 100..9999 LOOP
     INSERT INTO phones (`phoneid`,`phone`,`active`) VALUES (NULL, phone_number, "1");
   END LOOP;
END
//
```

I have got the following error

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near'FOR phone_number IN 100..9999 LOOP INSERT INTO phones (`ph' at line 2

What is wrong?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/loop.html

Comment: Loops are only allowed in stored programs.  Your code does not appear to be in a stored procedure, function, or trigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i don't think in mysql exists "for loop". you can use this:

```
DELIMITER //
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS ins//
CREATE PROCEDURE ins()
BEGIN
DECLARE cnt INT;
   SET cnt=100;
WHILE cnt<10000 DO
  INSERT INTO phones (`phoneid`,`phone`,`active`) VALUES (NULL, cnt, "1");
  SET cnt=cnt+1;
END WHILE; 
END//
DELIMITER ;

CALL ins();
```

Comment: Unknown system variable cnt

Comment: add this first `DECLARE cnt INT;`

Answer (score 0):

You may generate desired values even without stored code, like:

```
INSERT INTO phones (
  `phoneid`,
  `phone`,
  `active`
) 
SELECT 
  NULL, 
  n0.n+10*n1.n+100*n2.n+1000*n3.n AS num, 
  "1" 
FROM 
  (SELECT 0 AS n UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) AS n0 
  CROSS JOIN 
  (SELECT 0 AS n UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) AS n1
  CROSS JOIN 
  (SELECT 0 AS n UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) AS n2
  CROSS JOIN 
  (SELECT 0 AS n UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) AS n3
HAVING
  num>99
```

These `CROSS JOIN` will produce values `0..9999`, so you'll have to filter those which are below `100` (that's why it has `HAVING` clause)